# Запись значений в excel по условиям

Tags: c#, массивы, excel

помогите реализовать, или посоветуйте вектор направления, я новичок в этом деле. Суть такова, читается excel файл, обрабатывается, и создаётся новый, так вот, массив типа list[3,j] 3- колонка, j - строка, входящая информация к примеру "Зеленый", она указывает что в колонках с 10 по 50 нужно поставить 1 а в колонках  17 и 19 установить 0.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не актуален, вышел из положения:

```
        string z = "Вариант 1";
                    string[] myArry =
                    { 
        "Вариант 1",
        "Вариант 2",
        "Вариант 3",
        "Вариант 4",
        "Вариант 5"
};
        int a=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
     if (z == myArry[ar]) 
    { 
       Console.WriteLine(myArry[ar]);
       Console.WriteLine("есть");
    }
     else 
    { 
      Console.WriteLine("нет");
    }
    ar++;
```

Может конечно быть красивее, но пока на что способен.